# Making a cross-compatible application

Tags: windows, macos, operating-system

I am interested in starting application creation, and I am wondering how I can make applications that work on both mac and windows. Without having to code separate applications to do the same thing (using Xcode or Microsoft Visual C++ respectively), I want to write an application using one standard program or language that would let me run this app on either OS'
EDIT: Any programming language is fine.

Comment: With http://www.xamarin.com nad their http://www.mono-project.com/ .NET is another option to QT and C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QT is a cross-platform C++ framework for developing Desktop and Mobile applications: http://qt-project.org/

Comment: This would allow me to make an application that runs the same in both Mac and Windows?

Comment: Yes, the application will look and run the same on both platforms.